# Addition on pointers and operator precedence

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int myMatrix[2][3] = { { 11, 12, 13 }, { 21, 22, 23 } };
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     { std::cout << *(*myMatrix + i) << std::endl; }
```

This is an example from one of my lectures.
The output is "11 12 13 21 22 23"

I don't understand why this is working.

`*(*myMatrix + i) = *(11 + i)` The * operator should have higher precedence than +.

This is how I think it should work, which would result in an error because you can't dereference integer value 11.

I'm clearly missing something, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `*myMatrix` isn't `11` , that's how. It is equivalent to `myMatrix[0]`, which expresses as the address of the first element of the array of three `int` at that residence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 2D array of **two rows** and **three columns**

In other words, you have a **pointer array of size 2**. Let's suppose we call this array as ***array1***.

Now, each index of this array1 further points to an **integer array of size three**. This means that it contains **two addresses** which are of the following two arrays.

Let's say that array1[0] points to **array2** and array1[1] points to **array3** (By pointing it means, array1[0] contains the address of first element of array2 and array1[1] contains address of first element of array3)

array2 will contain these items:  { 11, 12, 13 }

array3 will contain these items: { 21, 22, 23 }

Now, consider your code and try to dry run it one step at a time

```
{ std::cout << *(*myMatrix + i) << std::endl; }
```

Note that myMatrix contains the **address** of the first element of your **pointer array**, i.e. **Address of array1[0]**.

`std::cout << *(*myMatrix + i) << std::endl;`

For the value of **i = 0**

```
cout << *(*myMatrix + i ) 
cout << *((Address of array1[0]) + 0) 
cout << *(Address of array1[0]) 
cout << 11 // Dereferencing that address will give you 11
```

Similarly, for **value of i = 1**, it will be,

```
cout << *(*myMatrix + i ) 
cout << *((Address of array1[0]) + 1) 
cout << *(Address of array1[1]) // added 4 bytes into the address of array1[0] will give you array[1]'s address
cout << 12 // Dereferencing that address will give you 12
```